# Suggested Edits Page has poor CSS

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, suggested-edits

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits
2. Examine Review Box

Observed value: Review box has same coloring as above announcement

Expected value:  Review box would have different coloring or different font colors to be more legible.

[image]

OS: Windows Vista
Browser: Chrome
Page: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits

Comment: Confirmed, same result on Safari under OS X.

Comment: This has been mentioned at various points. We're not the only ones hit by it.

Answer (score 2):

Will be fixed in the next deploy, sorry about that

Comment: This is not quite fixed yet -- the number (listed in the orange square box) of review items is approximately the same color as the box itself, making viewability quite hard.